# CSS - internal vs external + important! rule

Tags: css

I have the same rule which the first is in external .css file and the second is internal via  ...
In the ex

`.img1 { background-image: url("....") !important; }` 
<-- declared inside .css file and added via  to the code

`.img1 { background-image: url("....") !important; }` <-- declared inside the code via  in the  part.

It seems that the external + important overides the internal + important.

How come? and what can be done to fix it besides taking off the important! rule in the external css rule

Thanks

Comment: To be honest.. in years of coding I've not once EVER found the need to use the !important rule, ever. If you think logically about structure you can completely control anything without using !important. I'd remove both !important declarations and your problem is solved.

Comment: +1 to @Scott's comment, `!important` declarations break the natural cascading, try to avoid them like the plague if you can. If both declarations are identical, which are you declaring first/last? Try to import the one that you want to have precedence as the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like this is about the css selector-precedence, wich is basically:

- if different rules apply to the same element, the more specific rule is used (`p.class` is better than just `.class`)
- it the rules are the same, the later one is used
- rules containing `!important` are preferred over the "normal" ones everytime
- if two rules containing `!important` apply to the same element, the more specific one or the later one is used

to read more about this, take a look at http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

later = further down in the came css-file or content of the css-file included further down in the same html-document.